# Vertical column cursor highlighting in text editor?

Tags: cursor, editor, indentation, highlight

I'm looking for a basic text editor or a plugin for an existing editor that can highlight the entire current column or vertical location of the cursor similar to the common option to highlight the entire currently selected row or line.

I think it would be very useful for indented code.

Does anyone know where I can find something like this?

Answer (score 3):

I understand exactly what you're looking for and want it myself.  I use Notepad++ (based on Scintilla) but there doesn't seem to be a "highlight current column" option the way they *do* provide for "highlight current line".

I looked at the plugin architecture and demo plugin package.  I whipped up a proof of concept - very basic, surely buggy, that uses the long lines edge column indicator as the "highlight" for current cursor column.  Not the best solution since if you're using the edge indicator, you "lose" it.

Source code on GitHub:

https://github.com/vinsworldcom/nppColHighlight

Answer (score 0):

[**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

It's based on the [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) library which implements exactly that feature you're describing, basically highlighting a rectangular area.

To do so, hold `Alt` + `Left Mouse` or `Alt` + `Shift` + `Arrow Keys` to select.

Comment: To clarify, I don't mean select but just highlight. I want it to highlight the current column of the cursor, like how Notepad++ and others highlight the current row of the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't found such an editor, PSPad editor has the feature.
Link: https://www.pspad.com/
Please see the attached screenshot (don't worry about the editor language in my screenshot, English (and several other languages) are also available).
[PSPad editor with vertical line showing the current cursor position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI5cC.png)